# Can't bring up the menu bar while in full screen mode in El Capitan

Tags: menu-bar, fullscreen, macos

In Yosemite I could move the mouse to the top of the screen and the menu bar would show but under El Capitan it remains hidden. Is this a bug or is there a new way to display the menu bar while in full screen mode in 10.11?